# Sending commands to a window in tmux

Tags: tmux

I want to run a minecraft server in tmux and send commands to the server
window from a bash script.

Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting vanilla server..."
sleep 2
# Start a new session with name MC
tmux new-session -d -s MC

# Start minecraft in a new window named UHC
tmux new-window -t MC:1 -n 'UHC' 'java -Xms512M -Xmx1G -jar Minecraft.jar nogui'

# And attach to it
tmux a

# Wait 10 seconds
sleep 10

# Run a command
tmux send-keys -t MC:1 'worldborder get' Enter
```

The server starts but the command is not sent.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

*tmux*’s `attach-session` command does not exit until the client detaches (or its session goes away); your script is effectively paused, waiting for the `tmux a` command to finish.

You probably want to arrange to attach as the last step in your script (unless you have some command that you want to run right after the client detaches).

If you want to view the window (through the attached client) while that sleep is happening (e.g. to watch the Minecraft server start up), you could have *bash* run the `sleep` and `tmux send-keys` in the background:

```
tmux new-session -d …
tmux new-window …
{
    sleep 10
    tmux send-keys …
} &
tmux attach-session …
```